# Why is chrome offseting my <a> abit too high (vs FireFox)

Tags: css

I am lost at how can I fix this problem ... Chrome is the top 1 and FireFox below

[image]

CSS looks like

```
#mainnav ul {
    background: #a51c10;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(60,60,60,0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(60,60,60,0.8);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(60,60,60,0.8);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

#mainnav li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 2px;
    position: relative;
}

#mainnav a:link, #mainnav a:visited {
    padding: 4px 10px 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #a29061;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

**UPDATE**

it looks alittle different somehow from the working site (I dont think I can post a link tho) but copy & paste CSS

http://jsfiddle.net/aM8rn/4/

it appears I should put line-height: 1em in the `#mainnav ul`

http://jsfiddle.net/aM8rn/5/

Comment: please provide html code also

Comment: @corroded, actually I did that already. I think StackOverflow needs time to update that

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid this sort of problems is always a good idea to reset the default style: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: I did have a reset the HTML5 doctor reset

Answer (score 0):

putting line-height on the #main nav ul is making the link overlap the outer box for me..

I'd suggest not using line-height at all. You have px padding on your links to try to get them to match the outer `ul`'s line height, there might always be 1px differences if you try to do that.

instead I tried to let the outer container expand as required with the links themselves, in order to do this they had to be `display: block;` and for your inline `li` elements to remain side-by-side with blocks inside them, they had to become inline-blocks.

with this fiddle every px can be controlled with the padding on the `a`'s - http://jsfiddle.net/g5AXG/1/

I know you probably don't want a top bottom "border" but I marked where how it can be removed.. the negative wordspacing  is because inline-blocks, the `li`'s,  will naturally have about 3-4px between them (like words) I didn't think it made a difference to the aesthetics of your menu if it was there or not, but put it in anyway